# Inline CSS to create a row of horizontal images

Tags: html, css, drupal, web

I work for a University that uses drupal 6 and I have very little flexibility with Drupal. I need to use in-line css to create a row of 4 horizontal images.

Comment: Frankly, with Drupal, it's sometimes easier just use a frakkin' table.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
div {display: block;}
img {display: inline;}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="imgURL" />
<img src="imgURL" />
<img src="imgURL" />
<img src="imgURL" />
</div>
```

Comment: So I can copy and paste this into the wysiwyg editor built into drupal? Where would I put the CSS part as when I put that into the box it just shows up as text

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table if I had to use inline css. The basic code for the table would look like the below code. You can set the width to % or fixed px.

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;">
<tr>
    <td width="25%">image 1</td>
    <td width="25%">image 2</td>
    <td width="25%">image 3</td>
    <td width="25%">image 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you want spacing you can add cell padding and a direction. The below code will make 10px padding to the left cell.

```
<td width="25%" style='padding:0px 0px 0px 10px'>
```

You can see these examples in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szESW/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more images (gallery etc.), you can use float layout like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
    <img src="imgURL" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery { background: #fee; }
#gallery::after { clear: left; display: block; content: ""; }
#gallery img { display: block; width: 150px; margin: 20px; }
```

Layout is flexible and images count per line is dependent on actual #gallery div width.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can add your css. Either add the css in your theme folder
sites/all/themes or you can add the inline css in your editor.For adding it as inline css all you have to do is when you save the node, select the input format as PHP code, this way you can add your inline css.

You can either add your inline css as
    `drupal_set_html_head('<style>
    #gallery { background: #fee; }
    #gallery::after { clear: left; display: block; content: ""; }
    #gallery img { display: block; width: 150px; margin: 20px; }
    </style>
    ');`

or you can call a css file which is added in your module.

```
drupal_add_css( $your_module_path . 'your_css_file.css');
```